# How do I write add right angle connectors with comments above terms of an equation

Tags: equations, arrows, notes

I noticed today the following image on the banner of TEX Exchange.

[image]

I tried to replicate but I couldn't. Can someone help me replicate the right angle connectors (that's the best way I can describe them) for oxidation and reduction?

Comment: Please provide the fully compilable code of your attempt.

Comment: You can find a link to the code at https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/649/36296

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an example of the [chemmacros](https://ctan.org/pkg/chemmacros) package. See its doc (section 7.1.2. Redox Reactions).

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemmacros,chemformula}

\begin{document}

\ch{
  2 "\OX{o1,\ox*{0,Na}}" + "\OX{r1,\ox*{0,Cl}}" {}2
  ->
  2 "\OX{o2,\ox*{+1,Na}}" {}+ + 2 "\OX{r2,\ox*{-1,Cl}}" {}-
}
\redox(o1,o2)[green,-stealth]{\small oxydation}
\redox(r1,r2)[purple,-stealth][-1]{\small reduction}

\end{document}
```

[image: redox equation formatted with chemmacros]